# Where to put the try catch blocks

Tags: java, return, try-catch, controls

I have a button which gets a list of files into an array then calls a WwritefiletoDB function for each file:

```
private void BtnImportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // Create array to store filenames
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    JTextFiles.append("*** Current Files Processing ***\n");
    File dir = new File(TextFieldDirectory.getText());
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
        }
    });
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            JTextFiles.append(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
            try {
                writefiletoDB(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    JTextFiles.append("*** Finished Processing ***\n");
}
```

Note the try catchblocks.

The writefiletoDB method has this code:

```
public void writefiletoDB(String currentfile) throws SQLException, IOException {
    //System.out.println("This is current file:" + currentfile);
    PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(currentfile));
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    List fields = acroForm.getFields();
    PDField EventNo = acroForm.getField("EventNo");
    System.out.println("Event String Length: " + EventNo.getValueAsString().length());
    // If event number too short - then skip record
    if (EventNo.getValueAsString().length() != 10) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, currentfile +" record was skipped - invalid EventNo = " +EventNo.getValueAsString());
        JTextFiles.append("The above file skipped - the event number was incorrect length\n");
        pdfDocument.close();
        return;
    };

    Iterator fieldsIter = fields.iterator();
    // Create Hashmap "pdf" storing PDF field names & values
    Map<String, String> pdf = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (fieldsIter.hasNext()) {
        PDField field = (PDField) fieldsIter.next();
        // Next line removes braces for dropdowns and any leading whitespace
        pdf.put(field.getPartialName(), field.getValueAsString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").trim());
    }

    //Create list "columns" to store field names from Database
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmnt = null;
    try { 
        //Connect to DB
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + TextFieldDatabase.getText());
       stmnt = conn.createStatement();  
    } catch (SQLException se) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A SQL Error: " +se, "SQL ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);            
             return;
    }


    // Check If Event Number already exists in DB - if so then exit
    System.out.println("Checking if event exists");
    PreparedStatement psEvent = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT EventNo FROM test WHERE EventNo = ?");
    psEvent.setString(1, EventNo.getValueAsString());
    ResultSet rsEvent = psEvent.executeQuery();

    if (!rsEvent.next()) {
        System.out.println("Result set is empty");
    } else {
        JTextFiles.append("The above record already exists - skipping\n");
        pdfDocument.close();
        return;
    }

    // Get a list of column names from database
    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test WHERE False");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    //System.out.println("Column names as reported by ResultSetMetaData:");

    // Add the column names from database to List columns
    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        // Store the column names from DB in list columns (via result set rsmd)
        columns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
    }

    // col and val strings to be built colname,colname and ?,?,?,? etc
    // for sql prepared statement into DB
    StringBuilder col = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";
    for (String c : columns) {
        if (pdf.containsKey(c)) {
            col.append(separator).append(c);
            val.append(separator).append("?");
            separator = ",";
        }
    }

    // Insert into DB SQL Statement
    String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO test (%s) VALUES (%s)", col.toString(), val.toString());

    System.out.println(
            "This is sql statement: " + sql);
    try (PreparedStatement insert = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        //Insert position in statement
        int pos = 0;
        //Second iterations: Bind the values to the statement *** colums is names of cols fromDB
        for (String c : columns) {
            //Your PDF has a matching formfield ** pdf is hashmap <string,string>
            if (c.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                System.out.println("A Date field has been found: " +c);
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm");
                DateTime startdt = formatter.parseDateTime(pdf.get("DateStart") +" " +pdf.get("TimeStart"));
                long millis = formatter.parseMillis(pdf.get("DateStart") +" " +pdf.get("TimeStart"));
                Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(millis);
                insert.setTimestamp(++pos, timeStamp);
            }
            if (pdf.containsKey(c) && !c.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                insert.setString(++pos, pdf.get(c));
            }
        }
        insert.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //JFrame frame;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A SQL Error: " +e, "SQL ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

Note the try catch block, about line 30. If it generates a error the return statement breaks and it returns to the calling method BtnImportActionPerformed and that loops calls the next file generating another error.

I need a way to break out of both writefiletoDB and also stop BtnImportActionPreformed.

Is there a way to handle writefiletoDB exceptions in BtnImportActionPreformed? or break out of both.

What is the best way to do this - I want to make the code more robust.

Thanks

Al

Comment: I'm not sure i understand correctly but, what i understand is that you just need a `break;` statement in your catch blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your example to the relevant structure, the code is doing this:

```
void BtnImportActionPerformed() {
    for(int i = 0l i < 10; i++) {
        writefiletoDB();
    }
}

void writefiletoDB() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Since the exception is being caught *and handled* in the inner method, there's no way for the outer method to know that anything went wrong.  If you want the outer method to know that an exception has occurred, use the same pattern as the inner method.  Catch a thrown exception.  Something like this:

```
void BtnImportActionPerformed() {
    for(int i = 0l i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            writefiletoDB();
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            // do anything else?
            return;
        }
    }
}

void writefiletoDB() throws SomeException {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        // log it?  something else?
        throw e;
    }
}
```

You might even be able to skip the inner try/catch entirely if the outer method can do all of the exception handling.  You'd simply have to declare the possible exceptions on the `writefiletoDB` method.

Comment: Right so you are catching the exception in the inner method then throwing it again to be caught by the outer method?

I didnt realise that exceptions are thrown up (but I do now) so could I not just catch the exceptions in BtnImportActionPerformed? and have no handling in writefiletoDB ?

Comment: @AlGrant: That's really a logic question for you.  An exception can indeed be caught anywhere along the call stack.  Where it *should* be caught is wherever it can be meaningfully handled.  Sometimes that can involve multiple catches because each method has its own way of partially handling it within the context of that method, perhaps adding information to the exception before re-throwing it.  Sometimes not.

Comment: Thanks - working nicely now.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, I would choose depending upon what is right for your logic.

- Do not catch any exception and let the caller of `BtnImportActionPerformed` catch.
- Put try catch around the for loop of `BtnImportActionPerformed` that way once exception is raised you are out of the loop. Do remove the try/catch inside the for loop.
- From the `writefiletoDB` return success/failure instead of exception. In `BtnImportActionPerformed` based on the success/failure you can exit the loop.